# Plots not displayed in pdf when rendering Rmarkdown from bash script

Tags: r, bash, pdf, ggplot2, r-markdown

I need to compile my R-markdown file to `pdf` from a `bash` script.
I am using Rstudio 1.1.383, and I am using the following script-

```
Rscript -e "library(knitr); knit('myfile.Rmd')" 
Rscript -e "library(rmarkdown) render('myfile.md')"
```

This produces the `pdf`, but the `ggplots` and `rpart` plots are created as separate `.png` files in a figures folder.
If I use the knitr button in Rstudio the plots are compiled to the pdf perfectly.
So I guess my script is not mimicking the knitr button properly.
This is what one of the code chunks looks like for a ggplot

```
{r,fig.cap="Box plots for standardized data" }

melted = melt(Scaled_df)
ggplot(data = melted) +  geom_boxplot(aes(x=Species,y=value, fill = Species)) +   facet_wrap(~variable) +
  theme(axis.ticks = element_blank(), axis.text.x = element_blank())
```

But I guess that must be OK, because a pdf compiled using knitr button in Rstudio is perfect.
Does anyone know what's wrong with my bash script?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [documentation](https://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/authoring_quick_tour.html#rendering_output)  explains::

> If you are not using RStudio then you simply need to call the 'rmarkdown::render function, for example:

```
rmarkdown::render("input.Rmd")
```

> Note that in the case using the “Knit” button in RStudio the basic mechanism is the same (RStudio calls the rmarkdown::render function under the hood).

So in your case, you should not knit the intermediate markdown file.

Comment: Yes, that does it - perfectly replicates the knitr button. Many Thanks